# how to shuffle columns of an array?

Tags: python

```
from sklearn import datasets
X, y = datasets.make_friedman1(n_samples=numSamples, n_features=numFeatures,
                                                 noise=NOISE, random_state=randomSeed)
```

the returned X has a number of columns equal to numFeatures. I like to shuffle the column of X array. How to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code is to change randomly order of columns, if it is what you meant.

```
import numpy as np
X = X[:, np.random.permutation(X.shape[1])]
```

if you want to change order of rows do samely next:

```
X = X[np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])]
```

As it is probably a data science task then I think you wanted to change the order of rows, this is a regular task of shuffling a dataset, changing order of samples (but not features), so second code is what you really need, not first.

For shuffling rows (0-th axis) a shorter syntax is also possible:

```
X = np.random.permutation(X)
```

or even shorter, which does in-place change of array, no assign operator needed:

```
np.random.shuffle(X)
```

Comment: Thanks Arty. The first option is what I wanted and it works. I appreciate it